# How to avoid NullPointerException Junit RestTemplate

Tags: java, junit

i'm working in spring project where i have a service that call another api using Restemplate , this service return just a string as a token and all works fine for me , this is my service :

```
@Service
public class AppServiceImpl {

    @Value("${rest.appUrl}")
    private String appUrl;

    @Value("${credType}")
    private String credType;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public String getToken() {

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();

        map.add("grant_type", credType);

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(map, headers);

        ResponseEntity<TargetObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(appUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, TargetObject.class);

        TargetObject targetObject = response.getBody();

        return "Bearer " + targetObject.getToken();

    }

}
```

my problem is when i want to unit test this service i'm getting NullPointerException and i dont know why , this is my unit test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class AppServiceImplTest {

    private AppService appService = new AppServiceImpl();

    @Test
    public void getTokenTest() {

        String token = appService.getToken();

        assertTrue(token != null);
    }

}
```

the NullPointerException in this line :

```
ResponseEntity<TargetObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(appUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, TargetObject.class);
```

do you have any idea what's the problem with my test ? i spent hours without any result

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that in your service you autowire `restTemplate`, but in your test you initialize your class by yourself, and not through spring, and there for it is not initialized and remains null.

if you are initializing the service by yourself in the test, make sure to add a mocked instance of `restTemplate`. I suggest moving the autowire in the service to be c'tor based, and then it will be easy to do so in the test:

```
 @Service
 public class AppServiceImpl {

    private String appUrl;
    private String credType;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public AppServiceImpl(RestTemplate restTemplate, @Value("${credType}") String credType, @Value("${rest.appUrl}") String appUrl) {
      this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
      this.credType = credType;
      this.appUrl = appUrl;
    }

...
...
...
}
```

and later in your test:

```
@Mock private RestTemplate restTamplate;
private AppService appService;

@Before
public void setup() {
  appService = new AppServiceImpl(restTamplate);
}
```

Comment: hello @Nir i made the changes that you said but still same problem Nullpointer Exception in this line ResponseEntity<TargetObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(appUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request, TargetObject.class);

Comment: did you debug it? what is null there, still the restTemplate? is it defined correctly in the test code or null there too?

Comment: no the response is null when i call response.getBody() it gives me NullPointerExcep

Comment: @James so you're missing the `Mockito.when()` assignments for your restTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Use Mockito It will resolve your issue.

```
ResponseEntity<TargetObject> response = restTemplate.exchange(appUrl, HttpMethod.POST, 
     request, TargetObject.class);
```

junit for above code would be:

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

TargetObject targetObject = new TargetObject();
targetObject.setToken("123456");
Mockito.when( restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class), 
   Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),Mockito.any(TargetObject.class)).thenReturn(targetObject);
```